# Prevent google from indexing "deny_all" = error 403

Tags: nginx, indexing

I have for example a directory who I won't like google to index (it's already indexed) which is example.com/img

Then in my Ngnix configuration I use:

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
```

That returns a 403 error without headers.

I read about adding headers such as:

```
add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
```

But I've found that they are not attached to a 403 error.

So, how can I prevent google from indexing?

P.S. I already have robots denying that directory, but Google search console is saying that it has to be fixed with noindex.

Comment: What is the exact problem, that the 403 is being indexed?

Comment: @Rafael yes, that's the first problem, and the second is that Google console is telling me I have to fix either the robots to allow that 403 page or add noindex to it so they can delete it

Comment: "you can also return an X-Robots-Tag header with a value of either noindex or none in your..."

Comment: @Rafael yep, but add_header X-Robots-Tag is not compatible with error 403

Comment: You never did mention your directory path, but that regex looks conventional, did you intend that?

Comment: well, if I have a problem with one of the directories, sooner or later I'll have with others, so I was trying to search a global solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to return a 403 and instead want to modify the responses to have this X-Robots-Tag header with a value of noindex or none (according to [Block search indexing with 'noindex'](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en)):

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    add_header "X-Robots-Tag" "none";
}
```

1. Remove the `deny` directive
2. add the `add_header` directive

[Read more @ Module ngx_http_headers_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html)

Comment: thank you! and is it the correct way to do it right? I'm unsure about what type of error will that return, 200? because if shouldn't be 200 no?

Comment: If you want a global solution just put the `add_header` directive statement above in your `http` or `server` blocks. It will modify every response to have that header and google will not index anything.

Comment: that's another solution, but I will get the whole web desindexed :(

Comment: I thought you just said that you wanted a "global solution?" If you don't want a global solution, then this needs to be in a `location` context to only modify responses therein.

Comment: Yeah, if you need to target a specific location, [read here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).